# Calculate dates between now and a specific date

Tags: date-time

I am trying to have a calculated item between two dates. What I am hoping to do is, get this item to calculate the date difference between now and another date (provided by the submitter)

I tried =DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Start Date in Current Role], "D") but getting an error message.

Answer (score 0):

What's the error you are getting? #Name or #Num? The DATEDIF() function does not like negative numbers. You could try:

```
=DATEDIF([Start Date in Current Role],TODAY(), "D")
```

If the dates do not include times (i.e. not 7/1/2018 3:34 PM), the formula can be as simple as:

```
=TODAY() - [Start Date in Current Role]
```

If they do include times, and the time portion is to be ignored then:

```
=INT( TODAY() ) - INT( [Start Date in Current Role] )
```